# How to create sub folders under cache of an application using getExternalCacheDir()?

Tags: android, caching

In my application I want to save some documents in my application cache. After use I want to clear that files from cache. If I clear the cache all saved data's will be loss but I don't want that. I need to create a sub folder under my cache and I want to read data's from that cache folder also after certain uses I wanted to clear data's present in that particular folder.

How can I do that using `getExternalCacheDir()`?

I tried using following snippet,

```
File tempFile = new File(AppDelegate.sharedDelegate().getExternalCacheDir()+"\documentfolder\", name + ext);
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
outputStream.close();
return tempFile;
```

But I am getting

```
System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.debug/cache/documentcache/Screenshot_20171108-011217.png.png (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

getCacheDir(). It returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory

```
File myDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "yourfolder");
myDir.mkdir();
```

then create file using below code.

```
File f = new File(your directyorypath + "filename.txt");

if (f.exists()) 
{
    f.delete();
}

f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: `myDir.mkdir();` That should be `if (!myDir.mkdir()) return;`.

Comment: `File f = new File(your directyorypath + "filename.txt");` That should be `File f = new File(myDir, "filename.txt");`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
File dir = new File(AppDelegate.sharedDelegate().getExternalCacheDir(), "documentfolder");
dir.mkdirs();
```

then use dir as parent folder for your file:

```
File tempFile = new File(dir, name + ext);

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
outputStream.close();
return tempFile;
```

Comment: how to clear the data;s present only in the sub directory not the whole cache?

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles() to find all files under `dir`, then iterate them and call `delete()` on `File` instances